# Query information about which data members function accesses

Tags: c++

Assume the following example code

```cpp
struct Bar {
    int x, y, z;
};

int foo(const Bar& bar) {
    return bar.x + bar.z;
}
```

Is there a way to automatically tell, that `foo` accesses `x` and `z` from bar, but not `y`? Maybe the compiler (any of gcc, clang, or msvc) can output something like that?

Comment: Some static code analysis tools do.

Comment: What do you actually mean "automatically tell"? Do you want to see a report, or does your code somehow need to be aware of it, or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One tool that can do this sort of thing is `clang-query`, which is
included in the
[Clang+LLVM distribution](https://releases.llvm.org/download.html).  `clang-query` searches the program's [Abstract Syntax Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) (AST) for code that matches the given pattern(s).

For example, here is a shell script that invokes `clang-query` to find member
accesses:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Run clang-query to find referenced members.

# Where I have Clang+LLVM installed.
CLANG_LLVM_DIR=$HOME/opt/clang+llvm-14.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-18.04

# This query reports member reference expressions (like "obj.field").
# It binds the name "field" to the matched field, and "func" to the
# function definition containing the reference.
query='m
  memberExpr(
    member(fieldDecl().bind("field")),
    hasAncestor(functionDecl().bind("func")))'

# Run clang-query.
"$CLANG_LLVM_DIR"/bin/clang-query -c="$query" "$@"

# EOF
```

The core of `query` is `memberExpr`, a matcher that reports any
expression that is an access of a member.  The rest is binding names to
relevant elements so they will be printed, as well as the member
expression itself.

When run on the input in the question, it prints:

```
$ ./cmd.sh test.cpp --

Match #1:

path_to_source/test.cpp:2:5: note: "field" binds here
    int x, y, z;
    ^~~~~
path_to_source/test.cpp:5:1: note: "func" binds here
int foo(const Bar& bar) {
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
path_to_source/test.cpp:6:12: note: "root" binds here
    return bar.x + bar.z;
           ^~~~~

Match #2:

path_to_source/test.cpp:2:5: note: "field" binds here
    int x, y, z;
    ^~~~~~~~~~~
path_to_source/test.cpp:5:1: note: "func" binds here
int foo(const Bar& bar) {
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
path_to_source/test.cpp:6:20: note: "root" binds here
    return bar.x + bar.z;
                   ^~~~~
2 matches.
```

This is reporting both of the accesses.

If you want to do more than just print the accesses, you will probably
need to write something like a `clang-tidy` check. Such a check uses AST
matchers like `clang-query`, but you can also write arbitrary
C++ code to process the matches.

References:

- [Clang AST Matcher Reference](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersReference.html)
- [Clang AST: MemberExpr](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1MemberExpr.html),
  which is one of many Clang AST nodes.  Although it is not necessary to look at the AST documentation to write matchers, I find it helpful since the matcher names are based on names in the main AST docs.
- [Writing custom `clang-tidy` checks](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/Contributing.html)
- Stephen Kelly blog: Exploring Clang Tooling Part 2: Examining the Clang AST with clang-query: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/exploring-clang-tooling-part-2-examining-the-clang-ast-with-clang-query
- Firefox blog:
  [Using clang-query](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/code-quality/static-analysis/writing-new/clang-query.html)