Retrieving from gcc/clang a value known at compilation time
Consider the following compilatiom time constant VALUE defined by
struct foo  {  uint32_t a;  };

static constexpr int VALUE = sizeof(foo);

Note that the way the value is computed is not important here.
I would like to retrieve the value itself (4 in the example) as a result of the compilation; in other words,I don't want to build a binary and launch it in order to get this value.
I know that option -E allows to stop after pre-processing but at this stage the value is not yet known. Maybe there exists some compiler option that would allow this but I don't know it.
The only way I can think of is to put a static_assert(VALUE==-1) that will cause an error and hope that the error message will hold the value; it seems that gcc can do this but not clang.
Is there a better way and not compiler-dependant to get the constant value as a result of the compilation itself ?

It is a tooling thing. Some of us use an IDE, like Visual Studio. There you put the mouse over either foo or VALUE and the size pops up.

Actually, I want get this value during a CMake process.

clang can do it as well https://godbolt.org/z/vf9Y6Y8Gx

"the way the value is computed is not important here." it actually is important, because if you could define it from outside and use it as paramter for compilation then the issue is gone. Would that be an option?

CMake can retrieve the output of a program, why not create small exe to get the value?

@Jarod42  The context is that the binary has to be built for a specific hardware; and it may happen that this hardware is not available while the compilation process, and so without possibility to launch the binary.

This:
template<auto> class error;
error<VALUE> print;

This prints:

clang error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'error<4>'
gcc error: aggregate 'error<4> print' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
icx error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'error<4>'
msvc error C2079: 'print' uses undefined class 'error<4>'

See for yourself on Compiler Explorer. On all of them, you could grep on error<[0-9]+> to retrieve the 4.

Alternatively, clang-query might be a viable solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73069843/query-information-about-which-data-members-function-accesses

With the C++26 feature of user-generated static_assert messages (P2741R3), you can calculate any string to be emitted at compile time:
// This can be replaced with `fmt::format("{}", x)`, or constexpr `std::format` in future C++ versions
consteval std::string to_string(std::integral auto x) {
    std::string result;
    constexpr std::size_t max_size = std::numeric_limits<decltype(x)>::digits10 + 2;
    result.resize_and_overwrite(max_size, [&x](char* p, std::size_t count) -> std::size_t {
        assert(count == max_size);
        auto [ last, ec ] = std::to_chars(p, p + max_size, x, 10);
        assert(ec == std::errc{});
        return last - p;
    });
    return result;
}

static constexpr int VALUE = sizeof(foo);
static_assert(false, "MARKER'" + ::to_string(VALUE) + "'MARKER");
// Compiler error output contains "MARKER'4'MARKER", which you can search for

You can have any message you want. Perhaps a constexpr JSON library for a more complicated output.
GCC claims to support this in GCC 14. It even accepts it as an extension in older C++ versions.
Clang supports this since Clang 17, but you have to have to be in -std=c++2c mode or it simply won't parse.

To identify the value of an enum at compilation time, update a simple list of #define after definition of enumeration, and use it (Booze::VINE just exists at compilation time)
enum Booze {
  GIN = 20000,
  VINE,
  VODKA
};

#define DEF_GIN Booze::GIN
#define DEF_VINE Booze::VINE
#define DEF_VODKA Booze::VODKA

int main () {
  int vin ((int) DEF_VINE);
  std::cout << "VINE = " << vin << std::endl;
  return 0;
}


#define doesn't add anything useful. OP wants to print at compile-time, not runtime.

You're missing the point I fear: OP wants an answer at compilation-time; yours provide one at run-time.
